# Which is correct: "Set up something" or "Set something up" or "Setup something"?

Tags: expressions

As a programmer, I often have to use this expression:

> Set the application up.

or something like that. But I'm not sure what the correct grammar is, and what this grammatical area is called in English.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both "set up something" and "set something up" are perfectly correct English, as "set up" is a phrasal verb.  As kajaco mentions, "setup something" is just a spelling error (although it is fairly common).

Of the two correct phrases, I don't think one is inherently more clear than the other, if the `something` part is short enough.  But, it is important not to let the two words separate too far.  That is, when the `something` part gets longer, it becomes increasingly worse to separate "set" and "up".

For example, these sound good, because "all of your accounts" is short enough:

> - I will **set** all of your accounts **up**. / I will **set up** all of your accounts.

But the following only really works if you don't separate the phrasal verb components:

> - ?I will **set** a table of all the people who haven't logged in since May **up**. (sounds awkward)
> - I will **set up** a table of all the people who haven't logged in since May.

If you are a non-native speaker, you might ask, "what is the line between too long and not too long?"  Well, there is no clear line that can be given as a rule.  But I would say that if the `something` part is more than 5 words, you might want to play it safe and keep "set" and "up" together.

Comment: Somebody set up us the bomb.

Comment: For some reason, it sounds awkward/incorrect to use the "set up X" construction when X is a pronoun.

Comment: @Jack: That is a good observation, and true of [all particle phrasal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb#A_diagnostic) in English. It's probably related to the fact that you can say "give him the ball" but you can't say "give him it". There are certain structures where English doesn't like to leave a bare pronoun at the end (because it's too "weak" or some similar stipulation). Note also that you can say "give it to him" and that's okay, because *him* is inside of a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @Kosmonaut There are regional differences; see [Is it incorrect to say 'Give me it?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9305/is-it-incorrect-to-say-give-me-it). // I think the terms 'MWV', 'transitive [MWV]', 'separable-optional', 'separable-obligatory', 'inseparable' are better defined and clearer. 'The Oxford Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs' (!) or its modern revision uses them (apart from MWV).

Answer (score 9):

"Setup" is noun, not a verb, so you wouldn't "Setup something".

"Set up something" keeps the two parts of the expression (set and up) together, so that seems clearest.

Other wording might work better: Install or initialize.

Comment: Here in the UK native speakers generally say 'set something up', 'set up something' is correct but sounds distinctly American from this side of the North Atlantic. C.f. Preposition order: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59368/order-of-preposition-in-us-and-uk-english

Answer (score 3):

Somebody did a pretty extensive analysis of this at ["Setup" Is Not a Verb](http://notaverb.com/setup).  You can probably guess from the title what the conclusion was!

Comment: meh.  If people use it like a verb then it is a verb.