# Direct object before indirect object

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, passive-voice, direct-objects, indirect-objects

In [this article](http://www.bartleby.com/224/1504.html) on the changes in English grammar the author says:

> How untrammelled the English passive is, may be seen in the fact that, not content with a construction like *“A book was given him,”* the language has devised *“He was given a book.”*

Can one really interchange the direct and indirect objects to get *"Someone gave a book him"* instead of *"Someone gave him a book"*? Does it sound informally, humorously or incorrectly?

Comment: *Someone gave a book **to** him.* You need to add a preposition if the indirect object is after the direct object.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it, but what did the author mean by this "He was given a book"?

Comment: The author means that ***both*** the indirect object and the direct object can be the subject when using the passive voice. *I gave John a book* can turn into *a book was given John (by me)* ***or*** *John was given a book (by me).*

Comment: The 'was given him' form predated and (formerly) was more frequent than the 'he was given' form.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(was+given+him)%2C(he+was+given)&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28was%20given%20him%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28he%20was%20given%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Tim: [both](https://books.google.com/books?id=DlRJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22he+was+given%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwA2oVChMIm6C924DexgIVxpqICh34Xgut#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20given%22&f=false) [forms](https://books.google.com/books?id=PEAPAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA400&dq=%22was+given+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMIk6jb-4DexgIV05yICh1qCgsP#v=onepage&q=%22was%20given%20him%22&f=false) appear in the 16th century, whereas your Ngram only starts at 1600. You can't really conclude anything about which was first from that Ngram.

Comment: By the way, here http://gameswithwords.org/ after a quiz it is said that *Americans, Canadians, and South Africans accept **I sent my mother a letter** instead of **to my mother***.

Comment: @se0808 - I think *any* variety of English accepts,  "I sent my mother a letter". British English certainly does. What we do not say is, "I sent a letter my mother" Instead we must say "I sent a letter **to** my mother."

Comment: It's not that simple, but in many cases [both orders are allowed](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/106899/15299). However, you have to be careful to get the prepositions and pronouns right.

Comment: See also [Is it incorrect to say 'Give me it'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9305/is-it-incorrect-to-say-give-me-it).

Answer (score 1):

*Someone gave a book him* is incorrect, ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence structure S-V-DO-IO

> Someone-gave-a book-him.

has fallen out of favor, and we now expect the reverse positions of the direct and indirect objects:

> Someone-gave-him-a book.

or that indirect object is replaced by the object of the preposition "to":

> Someone-gave-a book-to him.

The Ngram viewer shows a steep drop in published uses of "gave it him" over the last two hundred years.  But it wasn't always so.  Here's some dialogue from *All's Well That Ends Well*.

KING     ... This ring, you say, was yours?
DIANA   Ay, my good lord.
KING     Where did you buy it? or **who gave it you**?
DIANA   It **was not given me**, nor I did not buy it.
KING     **Who gave it you**?
DIANA   It was not lent me neither.
KING     Where did you find it, then?
DIANA   I found it not.
KING     If it were yours by none of all these ways, how could **you give it him**?
DIANA   **I never gave it him**

Comment: *Someone gave a book him* was ***never*** "in favor". Although *someone gave it him* (where the first object is a pronoun) indeed was.

Comment: @PeterShor and is still used today!

Comment: @Araucaria: I don't think anybody uses it in the US Northeast, but I'll take your word that it's still in use somewhere.

Comment: @PeterShor There's a little piece about research into "Give it me!" on [this page here](http://linguistics-research-digest.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/give-it-me_27.html)

Comment: @PeterShor Oh, yes, and a nice piece about the dialectical difference of it in relation to Am and B English [here too](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/she-gave-it-me.html)

Comment: @Peter Well, it was in favour in Old English, but not for long after that.