# Order of preposition in US and UK English

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

In Britain we'd say

> He had a black hat on.

Speakers of American English are more likely to say*

> He had on a black hat.

The latter just seems wrong to me. Is my intuition correct or are both equally valid usages?

---

* - according to Google NGram

Comment: The premise of the question is invalid. Americans are just as likely to use either sentence as British people are.

Comment: +1: @slim: do you have any evidence for this? 5arx: do you have any evidence for this? Ngrams actually shows that the use of "he had on a" [has declined quite a bit](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+had+on+a%2CHe+had+on+a&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) in Britain recently but [has not](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+had+on+a%2CHe+had+on+a&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) in the U.S. to the point where it's currently four times more common in the U.S. (although this wasn't true 50 years ago). So here the O.P. is right.

Comment: Let me add that speakers of American English also use "He had a black hat on" very frequently, as well ... I don't distinguish between these in meaning.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'm not sure what your NGram is designed to show. The difference between "he had on a" and "He had on a" is not a difference in word order, or the placement of a preposition, but whether the first word of the phrase is capitalized or not. Pardon me, but I don't get the connection.

Comment: @Robusto: if you add up the frequencies of "he had on a" and "He had on a" in British English. you get approximately .000005; if you add them up in American English, you get .000012, which is more than twice as large.  (And if you continue the Ngrams to 2008, you get .000003 and .000012, which is where my four times as large comes from.) Unfortunately, you can't put British and American usages on the same graph in Ngrams, which would show the difference much better.

Comment: @Peter Shor: In the first place, your sample only includes data from print sources (one of my big problems with Google NGrams, btw), and does not include *all* such sources. In the second, the difference between .000003 and .000012, while admittedly different by a factor of four, is still vanishingly small. Is the difference between 3 occurrences in 10 million really that different from 12 in 10 million? Surely that lies well within some margin of error, statistically speaking.

Comment: Your premise is false: ***on*** is **not a preposition** in the phrase “to have/put on one’s hat”.  Similarly with ***off*** in “to take off one’s hat” or “to turn off the light”. It doesn’t matter whether you move the little word, either, as in “to put one’s hat on”, “to take one’s hat off”, or “to turn the light off”. Note that Scots English and US English are both somewhat more apt to separate out the little word as in the last set of examples than you’re apt to find in the Home Counties. This is not new.

Comment: @Robusto: if you turn the smoothing to 0, you can see a lot of the year-to-year statistical variation in Ngrams. If you look at [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+had+on+a%2CHe+had+on+a&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=0) for British "he had on a", it looks to me like the level .000012 is well beyond the statistical margin of error.

Comment: @tchrist: Google Ngrams shows something happened to "had (on) a coat (on)" in British English around 1960 that didn't happen in American English, and didn't happen to "put (on) a coat (on)" in British English. Let me put this in an answer.

Comment: @PeterShor: Can you come up with a definition of what an acceptable statistical margin of error should be for NGrams to be included as comparative evidence? I still fail to see what your graph proves, given the fact that there are obvious flaws in the OCR collection of data in the first place, and that the data set itself is incomplete and may be biased in ways we cannot know.

Comment: @Robusto: I can't come up with such a definition (I expect a statistician could, with some amount of work). But looking at the blue line in the first Ngram in my answer, it is clear to me that the steep decline is not a statistical fluctuation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did notice that something is different between American and British usage of  "have on a hat". Let me show two Google Ngrams that illustrate the situation.

British:
[image]

American:
[image]

In [British English,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+on+a+coat%2Chad+a+coat+on%2Chad+his+coat+on%2Chad+on+his+coat&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=5) pre-1960, "had on a coat" is the most frequent of these expressions, followed by "had his coat on". However, "had on a coat" drops in frequency by a factor of nearly 30 by the 2000s.

In [American English,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+on+a+coat%2Chad+a+coat+on%2Chad+his+coat+on%2Chad+on+his+coat&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=5) these same two phrases are also the most common, but remain so for the entire period.

(Don't ask me why the most likely order of the preposition and the object depends on whether you use "a" or "his"; this is a piece of grammar that I obey, but I have no idea why. But either order is grammatical with either "a" or "his" in the U.S.)

To answer some of your questions:

(1) I think Americans are roughly equally likely to say "had a black hat on" and "had on a black hat". However, you are only noticing the second one, because this is a usage not found much in England anymore.

(2) If something was grammatical 50 years ago, I think it's a stretch to say that it is actually incorrect today. But you are right in that "had on a black hat" seems to be falling out of use in England.

What is going on here? *To have on* meaning *to wear* is a phrasal verb ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb#Phrasal_verb_patterns)) made up of a verb combined with a preposition<sup>1</sup>. For many phrasal verbs, the object can go either before or after the preposition. For some, like *to tell apart,* the object can only go before the preposition. For others, like *to take after,* the object must go after the preposition. What I suspect is happening is that, in England, *to have on* has changed (at least among the younger people) from the first kind of phrasal verb to the second.

<sup>1</sup> This preposition is sometimes called a *particle* because it does not behave grammatically like a preposition when it is part of a phrasal verb.

Comment: I believe you will find it called an *adverb* in that position.

Comment: @tchrist: some people do call it an adverb (see the wikipedia link above), but it doesn't behave grammatically like an adverb, either.

Comment: @PeterShor, on reflection what I perceive as the American usage does sound a little quaint/old fashioned and so is more correct in a sense. Your take on this makes sense to me. Great answer, many thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that the rules governing the placement of the particle depend on whether the object is a pronoun.  For example, "He put on the hat"; "He put the hat on"; and "He put it on"; but not *"He put on it".